# Aligning ListTile items when some of them don't have a leading object

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Here's what I have on the screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/brN5q.png

How can I align Last name so it's under First name ?
I don't want to put an icon next to Last name, just First name.

Here's the code I have. Thanks.

```
            body: Center(
            child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                            leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
                            title: new TextField(
                                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: "First name",
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                            title: new TextField(
                                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: "Last name",
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple & Elegant Way would be to use `Padding` Widget.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Form(
        //  key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
              title: new TextField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "First name",
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0)),
              title: new TextField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Last name",
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I understand correctly, the EdgeInsets padding is measured in pixels. Will that work regardless of device/resolution ? Will the fields remain aligned ? Is the Icon fixed in size ? If it won't look the same on different devices/resolutions, how can I achieve that ? I am new to Flutter and haven't worked with Android in a few years, so thanks for the patience.

Comment: We are Actually giving that exact space that is taken by the `leading:` in case of the `icon`. So yes it will works as expected on different devices & resolution. Its Like we have Invisible sapce there same as above icon.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an empty `Container` with fixed width as `leading` to the Last Name `TextField`, or you can wrap your Last Name `TextField` inside `Padding` and provide a some `padding` from left.

Example:

```
ListTile(
  leading: Container(
    width: 200.0, //You can adjust the width as required
  ),
  title: new TextField(
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
      hintText: "Last name",
    ),
  ),
),
```

OR

```
ListTile(
  title: Padding(
    padding: padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 200.0) //Adjust as required
    child: new TextField(
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
        hintText: "Last name",
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a quick hack by changing icon color to colors.transparent. I don't know if it's proper way though.

```
     body: Center(
        child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
                        title: new TextField(
                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "First name",
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.person,color: Colors.transparent),
                        title: new TextField(
                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Last name",
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is giving it an Icon with size 0, the ListTile will save the space even if there is nothing visible